# Spongy Castle in Android

Tags: java, android, random

Does Spongy Castle Provide the implementation of **"SHA1PRNG"** Algorithm? I am asking this because Bouncy Castle doesn't seem to provide implementation of "SHA1PRNG" Algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe too late for this answer, however, here is an example of the implementation:

SpongyCastle should be the same as BountyCastle, just usable in Android.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;


public class SHA1PRNG {
 //here i swapped out the bountycastle provider and used the spongycatle
   static {
      Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SecureRandom rng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    rng.setSeed(711);

    int numberToGenerate = 999;
    byte randNumbers[] = new byte[numberToGenerate];

    rng.nextBytes(randNumbers);
    for(int j=0; j<numberToGenerate; j++) {
        System.out.print(randNumbers[j] + " ");
    }

}
}
```

From: 
          www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/SecureRandomSHA1PRNG.htm